# Cross reference supporting information in class achemso

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files, achemso

By using the class achemso Supporting information to prepare the there to carry out a cross-reference (\ref{table:S1}} for this aquivo external "supporting.tex", example: Text ... see (Fig. S2) or (Table: 2), this is Suporting in a separate file.

Comment: Hi Fabio, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) `:)` We could not understand your question, could you rephrase it a bit? Se preferir, adicione uma versão em Português à sua questão original e eu tento traduzi-la para você. `:)`

Comment: Prezado Paulo Obrigado pela ajuda, desculpe pelo inglês

A questão é que do suporting Information, existe como referenciar um Figura do Supporting com o comando \ref{Fig:S1}, mais consultando a revista vi que não é possível fazer isso.

Talvez eu possa usar o \usepackage{xr}

Nesta pacote achemso não tem o modelo final (publicado) em relação a class da Elsevier

Acho que podem fechar o tópico

Comment: Fabio, é sempre um prazer ajudar os amigos! `:)` Quanto à sua questão, Joseph Wright vai comentar sobre ela amanhã. Abraço! `:)`

Answer (score 6):

The American Chemical Society (for whom `achemso` is written) provide only basic support for LaTeX submissions, and certainly do not use the LaTeX sources for final typesetting. I would therefore strongly recommend doing any cross-referencing between the main paper and Supporting Information 'by hand'. (It might be possible to use the `xr` package to produce cross-references, but this might go horribly wrong on submission so I would not do it!)

Comment: Ten years later, would you still recommend doing things by hand for `achemso`?

Comment: @andschar Yes: same workflow still applies